# Datorama (Marketing Intelligence) Calculated Dimensions AND statement

Tags: custom-reports, datorama

I'm trying to set up some custom filters to combine data from a few sources, using Calculated Dimensions.

I'm able to create a single filter using:

```
IF([Web_Analytics_Site_Campaign] contains 'registration','Spring Registration',
```

However if I try to add a second dimension using the AND function, it fails or ignores the code.

```
IF([Web_Analytics_Site_Campaign] contains AND('registration','fall'),'Fall Registration',
```

Not sure if I'm not reading the suggested function incorrectly or there's some odd typo I'm missing.

Answer (score 0):

The `AND` function in Datorama is used to check if multiple conditions are met, not to check if a string contains multiple substrings. To check if a string contains multiple substrings, you can nest multiple `IF` statements or use regular expressions.

Here's an example of how you could use nested IF statements:

```
IF([Web_Analytics_Site_Campaign] contains 'registration'
    AND [Web_Analytics_Site_Campaign] contains 'fall',
    'Fall Registration',
IF([Web_Analytics_Site_Campaign] contains 'registration'
    AND [Web_Analytics_Site_Campaign] contains 'spring',
    'Spring Registration',
'Other'))
```

Alternatively, here's an example of how you could use regular expressions to check if a string contains multiple substrings:

```
IF(REGEX_MATCH([Web_Analytics_Site_Campaign], '.*registration.*(fall|spring).*'),
    IF(REGEX_MATCH([Web_Analytics_Site_Campaign], '.*registration.*fall.*'), 'Fall Registration', 'Spring Registration'),
'Other')
```

Comment: Thanks @gvgramazio! This looks a lot more like I expected it would. 

I was trying something like this but didn't have any luck.

However, this is kicking back an error I believe due to the syntax.

`IF([Message_Send_Name] contains 'registration','Registration', 
IF([Web_Analytics_Site_Campaign] contains 'registration','Registration',
IF([Web_Analytics_Site_Campaign] contains 'registration'
    AND [Web_Analytics_Site_Campaign] contains 'fall',
    'Fall Registration',
   'Other'))
`

Malformed expression

Expected ")":5:5, found "AND WEB_AN"

Comment: Sorry for the poor formatting. tried to edit it and apparently there's a 5 minute delay. I tried looking for the documentation on this as well but didn't have any luck. If you have a link to some documentation that would be a huge help as well.

Answer (score -2):

please use below code.. let me know if you able to solve -

IF(
Contains([Web_Analytics_Site_Campaign], 'registration') AND Contains([Web_Analytics_Site_Campaign], 'fall'),
'Fall Registration',
IF(
Contains([Web_Analytics_Site_Campaign], 'registration') AND Contains([Web_Analytics_Site_Campaign], 'spring'),
'Spring Registration',
'Other'
)
)

Comment: This is the same as the existing answer, just with less information. Code dumps are not very good answers. The explanation is as important as the solution itself.